# Найти наиболее часто встречающийся элемент в массиве быстрее, чем за O(n²)

Tags: c

Задача следующая:

> Найти наиболее часто встречающийся элемент в массиве быстрее, чем за
>   O(n²). Если таких элементов несколько, вывести любой из них.

Моё решение работает хуже чем за О(n²). Буду очень признателен, если поможете подобрать и написать подходящий алгоритм быстрее чем за O(n²). Спасибо.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void generationArray(int* massif, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; size > i; ++i)
    {
        massif[i] = rand() % 10 - 5;
        printf("%d, ", massif[i]);
    }
}

void qsortArray(int* supportingElement, int first, int last)
{
    if (first < last)
    {
        int left = first, right = last, middle = supportingElement[(left + right) / 2];
        do
        {
            while (supportingElement[left] < middle) left++;
            while (supportingElement[right] > middle) right--;
            if (left <= right)
            {
                int tmp = supportingElement[left];
                supportingElement[left] = supportingElement[right];
                supportingElement[right] = tmp;
                left++;
                right--;
            }
        } while (left <= right);
        qsortArray(supportingElement, first, right);
        qsortArray(supportingElement, left, last);
    }
}

void arraySorting(int* massif, int size)
{
    generationArray(massif, size);
    qsortArray(massif, 0, size - 1);
    printf("\n\nSorted array:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", massif[i]);
    }
}

int differentiationOfNumber(int* firstArray, int size)
{
    int* secondArray = new int[size];
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        secondArray[i] = firstArray[i] - firstArray[i - 1];
    }
    secondArray[0] = firstArray[0];

    bool flag = false;
    int maxLen = 0;
    int maxIndex = 0;
    int len = 0;
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (secondArray[i] == 0 && flag)
        {
            len++;
            continue;
        }
        if (secondArray[i] == 0)
        {
            len++;
            index = i;
            flag = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (maxLen <= len)
            {
                maxLen = len;
                maxIndex = index;
            }
            len = 0;
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    delete[] secondArray;
    return firstArray[maxIndex];
}

void  printDifferentiationOfNumber()
{
    int size = 0;
    int number = 0;
    printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int* firstArray = new int[size];
    arraySorting(firstArray, size);
    differentiationOfNumber(firstArray, size);
    printf("\n%d\n", differentiationOfNumber(firstArray, size));
    delete[] firstArray;
}

bool differentiationTest(int* firstArray, int secondArray, int size)
{
    differentiationOfNumber(firstArray, size);
    int result = differentiationOfNumber(firstArray, size);
    return result == secondArray;
}

bool sortTest(int len, int array[], int sortedArray[])
{
    qsortArray(array, 0, len - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (array[i] != sortedArray[i])
        {
            return false;

        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int  differentiationTestArray[] = { -4, -3, 0, 1, 1, 1, -5, -5, -4, 1 };
    int maxIndex = 1;
    if (!differentiationTest(differentiationTestArray, maxIndex, 10))
    {
        printf("error");
        return 1;
    }

    int arrayFirstTest[] = { 5, -2, 8, 0, 1 };
    int sortedArrayFirst[] = { -2, 0, 1, 5, 8 };
    if (!sortTest(5, arrayFirstTest, sortedArrayFirst))
    {
        printf("Error");
        return 1;
    }
    const int length = 1000;

    int a[length]{};

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        a[i] = 1;
    }

    int correctArray[length]{};

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        correctArray[i] = 1;
    }

    qsortArray(a, 0, length - 1);
    if (!sortTest(length, a, correctArray))
    {
        printf("Error");
        return 1;
    }
    printDifferentiationOfNumber();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Реализовывать на чистом С можно O(N), но долго и сложно. Надо реализовать хеш-таблицу и вставлять в нее все элементы массива, если такой уже есть - увеличивать его счетчик.. Так как вставка в хеш-таблицу - O(1), вся вставка - O(N).

Затем пройти по всем элементам хеш-таблицы в поисках максимального значения (опять же O(N)). Итого - за O(N) задача разрешима.

На C++, конечно, проще всего: пусть исходный массив `int array[N];` (не компилировал - как иллюстрация идеи):

```
unordered_map<int> m;
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) m[i]++;
auto el = max_element(m.begin(),m.end(),
                      [](auto a, auto b) { return a.secong < b.second; });
cout << "Элемент " << el->first << " встречается " << el->second << " раз\n";
```

Достаточно просто реализовать на С алгоритм O(N log N) - сортировка + проход по массиву в поисках наиболее часто встречающегося - например:

```
int array[20] = { 1,2,3,4,9,2,3,4,9,3,4,9,3,4,5,9,8,8,9,1 };
qsort(array,20,sizeof(int),comp);

int last = array[0], count = 1;
int save = last, scount = 1;
for(int i = 1; i < 20; ++i)
{
    if (array[i] == last) ++count;
    else
    {
        if (scount < count)
        {
            scount = count;
            save   = last;
        }
        last   = array[i];
        count  = 1;
    }
}
if (scount < count)
{
    scount = count;
    save   = last;
}

printf("Element %d: %d times\n",save,scount);
```

Думаю, что эта реализация сможет обставить по скорости даже хеш-таблицу при реальных N, но, конечно, тут все зависит от реализации хеш-таблицы. Словом, нужно мерить...

Comment: можно не ходить по всем, а при вставке запоминать максимум

Comment: @teran Вы правы, можно так. Все равно O(N), но более быстрый :)

Comment: Ну, не так уж и сложно и на Си...

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего наиболее быстрым методом решения этой задачи будет сортировка (как сделали вы и как было показано в ответе @Harry). Если нельзя модифицировать исходный массив, то для подсчета проще всего сделать его копию.

Что касается хэширования, то эта процедура программируется на Си достаточно просто (см. ниже), однако имеет много подводных камней, связанных с распределением значений массива. В случае неудачной для конкретного распределения хэш-функции (например, для примера ниже это случай, когда в массиве размером 1000000 все элементы разные, но их младшие 20 бит одинаковы) мы получим огромное время вместе с огромным (опять же, для  примера ниже в 4 раза больше размера исходного массива) расходом памяти.

Если же мы знаем, как для данного набора символов написать эффективную хэш-функцию, а также знаем количество разных элементов массива, то можно (в случае примера ниже, задав соответствующие размеры в структуре хэш-таблицы) получить весьма эффективное как по памяти, так и по времени исполнения решение.

Когда диапазон значений элементов массива разумно мал (скажем, не превышает 1000000 (но для маленьких массивов разумно будет уменьшить этот диапазон до величины сопоставимой с размером массива)), то вместо "настоящего" хэширования для подсчета частот можно использовать массив счетчиков, индексируемый элементами массива.

Получим что-то такое:

```
  int ar_size, // размер массива
      size,    // диапазон
      from;    // нижняя граница

  int *ar = malloc(sizeof(int) * ar_size);
  for (int i = 0; i < ar_size; i++) // заполним массив как в коде вопроса 
      ar[i] = random() % size + from; 

  if (size < LSIZE) {  // LSIZE это упомянутая разумная граница
    int *cnt = calloc(sizeof(int), size);

    // установим счетчики частот элементов массива
    for (int i = 0; i < ar_size; i++) {
      int iv = ar[i] - from;
      cnt[iv]++;
    }

    // тривиальный поиск максимума
    int vmax = cnt[0], ivmax = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
      if (cnt[i] > vmax) 
        vmax = cnt[i], ivmax = i;

    free(cnt);

    printf("max freq %d for %d\n", vmax, ivmax + from);
  }
```

В противном случае, особенно если исходный массив нельзя модифицировать (использовать метод с сортировкой) можно построить хэш-таблицу счетчиков, в которой ключем поиска счетчика будет элемент массива.

Существует несколько видов хэш-таблиц с разными способами разрешения коллизий (т.е. ситуаций когда разные числа адресуют одно и то же место в таблице), различающиеся по эффективности поиска и размеру занимаемой памяти.

Для примера запрограммируем разрешение коллизий методом цепочек. В нем синонимы (т.е. разные числа, адресующие одно и то же место в таблице) помещаются в односвязный список. Обычно каждый элемент такого списка выделяется отдельным вызовом `malloc()`. В Linux x86-64 минимальный размер, выделяемый malloc это 32 байта. Поскольку мы хэшируем элементы массива `int` известного размера, то попробуем немного поэкономить память, выделяя под элемент цепочки коллизий всего 12 байт. Этого можно добиться, если вместо указателя (размер 8 байт) для адресации следующего элемента цепочки коллизий использовать индекс в массиве, в котором и размещать все эти элементы.

Получим такие структуры данных:

```
// элемент хэш таблицы, синонимы образуют список
struct htab_item {
  int val,  // число из массива `ar[]`
      cnt,  // счетчик 
      next; // индекс следующего элемента списка
};

struct htab {
  int hisize,   //  размер массива `.hindx`  (размер = ar_size, но его можно выбрать и другим)
      dsize,    //  размер массива `tabdata` (размер = ar_size)
      fdata;    //  первый свободный `htab_item` in `tabdata`
  int *hindx;   //  индексы начала цепочек коллизий в массиве `tabdata`
  struct htab_item *tabdata;
};

// функция для добавления нового элемента 
// возвращает его индекс в `tabdata`
int add_ht_item (struct htab *h, int v) {
  h->tabdata[h->fdata].val = v;
  h->tabdata[h->fdata].cnt = 1;
  h->tabdata[h->fdata].next = -1; // -1 означает, что это последний элемент цепочки коллизий

  return h->fdata++;
}
```

Правда, в этом случае приходится (если не усложнять все управлением некоторыми сегментами памяти) заранее выделить память с запасом под все элементы массива. Т.е. выделяем, предполагая пессимистический случай, что все элементы массива разные.

Ну, и код для заполнения хэш-таблицы и поиска наиболее часто встречающегося числа

```
struct htab ht = {ar_size, ar_size, 0,
                  malloc(ar_size * sizeof(int)),
                  calloc(ar_size, sizeof(struct htab_item))};

// инициализируем индексы свободных элементов таблицы числом -1
memset(ht.hindx, -1, ht.hisize * sizeof(int));

for (int i = 0; i < ar_size; i++) {
  unsigned int v0 = ar[i];
  int htix = v0 % ht.hisize;
  if (ht.hindx[htix] == -1)
    ht.hindx[htix] = add_ht_item(&ht, ar[i]);
  else {
    for (int j = ht.hindx[htix];;j = ht.tabdata[j].next) {
      if (ht.tabdata[j].val == ar[i]) {
        ht.tabdata[j].cnt++;
        break;
      }
      if (ht.tabdata[j].next == -1) {
        ht.tabdata[j].next = add_ht_item(&ht, ar[i]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

int vmax = ht.tabdata[0].cnt, ivmax = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < ht.fdata; i++)
  if (ht.tabdata[0].cnt > vmax)
    vmax = ht.tabdata[0].cnt, ivmax = i;


printf("max freq %d for %d\n", vmax, ht.tabdata[ivmax].val);

free(ht.hindx);
free(ht.tabdata);
```

Если что-то не понятно или интересно рассмотреть варианты, не стесняйтесь, спрашивайте в комментариях.

Answer (score 0):

От `O(N/2)` до `O(N)`:

```
    public static bool TryFindDominator<T>(T[] array, out T dominator) {
        int bound_value = (array.Length / 2);
        int current_dominator_count = 0;
        T current_dominator = default(T);

        Dictionary<T, int> item_count_table = new Dictionary<T, int>(array.Length);

        foreach (T item in array) {
            int count_value;
            if (item_count_table.TryGetValue(item, out count_value)) {
                count_value += 1;
            } else {
                count_value = 1;
            }
            item_count_table[item] = count_value;
            if (count_value > current_dominator_count) {
                current_dominator_count = count_value;
                current_dominator = item;

                if (current_dominator_count > bound_value)
                    break;
            }
        }

        dominator = current_dominator;
        return (current_dominator_count > bound_value);
    }
```

Comment: и где тут С?...

Comment: `O(N/2)` это хорошая сложность)))))))))))))

Comment: @timbars не лучше O(3/2N) и плюс ещё пару констант )))